# Google Slides Select Shape And Zoom to it

Tags: zooming, google-slides-api

I am trying to use the functionality of Google Slides to create a complicated diagram of a complicated process. Basically, I have tiny rectangles (shapes) within larger rectangles within even larger rectangles, all on top of a huge rectangle that occupies my entire viewport with the maximum zoom out (Ctrl-Alt-Minus pressed many times). Rectangles have some small font text in them and there are also a bunch of connectors going from one rectangle to another.

It's a big mess.

When I want to see the details of a small rectangle, I use the provided Ctrl-Alt-Plus shortcut to zoom in as far as it lets me. However, it's incredibly cumbersome, because it will only zoom in to whatever is in the very center of the screen. So, I need to constantly adjust my view port to place what I want into the center of the screen.

What I want is to write a script (if such functionality is in fact provided - hence the question) where I could click on a specific rectangle and it would immediately zoom to this rectangle, placing it in the middle of my screen, it occupying about 50% of the screen space.

I looked through Google Slides API reference and found absolutely nothing related to zoom. Am I searching incorrectly, or is it simply not there?

Comment: In the current stage, there are no methods for zooming object in the Slides API. But there is the method for selecting a object. You can see the detail information at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page-element#select()).

Comment: Actually, you know what, I just figured out something I should had tried but my brain somehow didn't go there. If I click on the "Magnifying Glass" icon, I can then specifically click on shapes that I am interested in and the zoom will go to that shape. So, in that regard everything is solved. Of course, I now have many new questions...